# How can I use the data of my project on another computer?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2014

I have a project in Visual Studio that I wrote in C#. I use SQL Server as database. I connect to the server as "local" and work on my own computer. I want to get my project "Setup" and install it on another computer.

When I install Setup on another computer, how should the connection sentence be written so that it can connect to SSQL Server database and work? Or what should I do?

**Note:** I am using Visual Studio 2019 and SQL Server 2014. With "Installshield 2018" I can install SQL Server 2014 package on a different computer.

My connection code:

```
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=mypc;Initial Catalog='StockControl';Integrated Security=True");
```

**Note 2**: I tried the code I wrote below this but it didn't work.

```
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|StockControl.mdf; Integrated Security = True");
```

I will be happy if you can help.

Comment: The IDE does not support other users running their IDEs on your set of files at the same time. I expect the same is true of the localdb database. Do you need a shared development environment or a SQL Server that supports remote connections from multiple users? A shared development environment implies something like SSDT and TFS rather than everybody pointing to the same code and database files with multiple IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your AttachDbFilename to: `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\StockControl.mdf`

See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string

For more information

Comment: When I try this I get an error like this: Unrecognized escape sequence

Answer (score 0):

localdb is a VS SQL variant meant for your local development environment.  It is possible to share a localdb for other users on the same computer, but that seems contrived.  If you want a database that supports remote connections (e.g., for staging or production), you should use a SQL express, dev, standard, or enterprise edition.  The dev edition is free.  These editions use services and don't depend upon your development environment to be running sql binaries.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15&redirectedfrom=MSDN&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014

For the connection string to a remote SQL Server, (localdb) should be replaced with the server name or IP.  There are web sites that have detailed examples.  One example is below.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Thanks, that helped.